# Hiding Branding, and LDAP Menu in the Admin Settings in Snipe-IT Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

So that I am using **Snipe-IT version 6** which is being built using **Laravel 8** as the asset management. And when I tried to hide the Branding, and LDAP menu on the Admin Settings by commenting the code in the `routes` folder, and `web.php` code. It turns out server error.

[image: see the image below]

My web.php is like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'authorize:superuser']], function () {
    Route::get('settings', [SettingsController::class, 'getSettings'])->name('settings.general.index');
    Route::post('settings', [SettingsController::class, 'postSettings'])->name('settings.general.save');

     // I commented on this code, to hide the menu appear on the admin setting
    // Route::get('branding', [SettingsController::class, 'getBranding'])->name('settings.branding.index');
    // Route::post('branding', [SettingsController::class, 'postBranding'])->name('settings.branding.save');

    Route::get('security', [SettingsController::class, 'getSecurity'])->name('settings.security.index');
    Route::post('security', [SettingsController::class, 'postSecurity'])->name('settings.security.save');

    Route::get('groups', [GroupsController::class, 'index'])->name('settings.groups.index');

    Route::get('localization', [SettingsController::class, 'getLocalization'])->name('settings.localization.index');
    Route::post('localization', [SettingsController::class, 'postLocalization'])->name('settings.localization.save');

    Route::get('notifications', [SettingsController::class, 'getAlerts'])->name('settings.alerts.index');
    Route::post('notifications', [SettingsController::class, 'postAlerts'])->name('settings.alerts.save');

    Route::get('slack', [SettingsController::class, 'getSlack'])->name('settings.slack.index');
    Route::post('slack', [SettingsController::class, 'postSlack'])->name('settings.slack.save');

    Route::get('asset_tags', [SettingsController::class, 'getAssetTags'])->name('settings.asset_tags.index');
    Route::post('asset_tags', [SettingsController::class, 'postAssetTags'])->name('settings.asset_tags.save');

    Route::get('barcodes', [SettingsController::class, 'getBarcodes'])->name('settings.barcodes.index');
    Route::post('barcodes', [SettingsController::class, 'postBarcodes'])->name('settings.barcodes.save');

    Route::get('labels', [SettingsController::class, 'getLabels'])->name('settings.labels.index');
    Route::post('labels', [SettingsController::class, 'postLabels'])->name('settings.labels.save');

    Route::get('ldap', [SettingsController::class, 'getLdapSettings'])->name('settings.ldap.index');
    Route::post('ldap', [SettingsController::class, 'postLdapSettings'])->name('settings.ldap.save');

    Route::get('phpinfo', [SettingsController::class, 'getPhpInfo'])->name('settings.phpinfo.index');

    Route::get('oauth', [SettingsController::class, 'api'])->name('settings.oauth.index');

    Route::get('google', [SettingsController::class, 'getGoogleLoginSettings'])->name('settings.google.index');
    Route::post('google', [SettingsController::class, 'postGoogleLoginSettings'])->name('settings.google.save');

    Route::get('purge', [SettingsController::class, 'getPurge'])->name('settings.purge.index');
    Route::post('purge', [SettingsController::class, 'postPurge'])->name('settings.purge.save');


    Route::get('login-attempts', [SettingsController::class, 'getLoginAttempts'])->name('settings.logins.index');

    // Backups
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'backups', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('download/{filename}',
            [SettingsController::class, 'downloadFile'])->name('settings.backups.download');

        Route::delete('delete/{filename}',
            [SettingsController::class, 'deleteFile'])->name('settings.backups.destroy');

        Route::post('/', 
            [SettingsController::class, 'postBackups']
        )->name('settings.backups.create');

        Route::post('/restore/{filename}', 
            [SettingsController::class, 'postRestore']
        )->name('settings.backups.restore');

        Route::post('/upload', 
            [SettingsController::class, 'postUploadBackup']
        )->name('settings.backups.upload');

        Route::get('/', [SettingsController::class, 'getBackups'])->name('settings.backups.index');
    });

    Route::resource('groups', GroupsController::class, [
        'middleware' => ['auth'],
        'parameters' => ['group' => 'group_id'],
    ]);

    Route::get('/', [SettingsController::class, 'index'])->name('settings.index');
});
```

If i uncomment it then the error is gone. What went wrong here? I just want to hide some menu which I don't need it on the admin settings. [image]

Comment: Check the server log to find the underlying error. A 500 code is generic and could mean almost anything

Comment: It just showing some maximum exceeding error, not the server cause of commented the code

Comment: What error, exactly? Is that in the php/laravel log? How do you know it's not the cause? Please realise that we cannot help you if you only provide vague, ambiguous information.

Comment: [Thu Sep 07 11:51:19.647960 2023] [php:error] [pid 9016:tid 1840] [client ::1:53909] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\OceanAMS\\vendor\\livewire\\livewire\\src\\ComponentConcerns\\ReceivesEvents.php on line 80, referer: http://localhost/oceanams/ I only got this for server log today

Comment: So it is timing out. If you try to load the page again do you get another timeout error?

Comment: No, there is no such a warning timeout error if I load it again.  That timout error is happening not cause I commented some code in the web.php, even I didn't do anything with the code it will gives me that errorr since the first time I run that Snipe-IT.

Comment: Never used Snipe-IT but removing a _route_ probably does not remove the feature. There most likely are places in code that reference that route name. See if there's something like "features" or "settings" or something in the "config" folder where you can disable features

Comment: `/resources/views/settings/index.blade.php` seems to be the template responsible for showing that "dashboard" page. There's a link to the route name you commented. You could probably remove features you don't want to show up by commenting HTML code there

Comment: Actually I hide some navbar menu, and side bar menu on the php file inside of the `resources/views/layout` path. In this folder there is some configuration of nav and side bar menu and I commented some of them, it is really hiding. But, I couldn't find the configuration of menu in the admin settings in this file of code

Comment: Actually I asked on [FB forum](https://web.facebook.com/groups/laravel/permalink/2698790610259278/), and there is someone says that he also using Snipe-IT, and he said that to add these line of codes in the index() method in the `app/Http/Controllers/Admin/SettingsController.php`  the code is something like this :```$this->nav_items['branding'] = false;
$this->nav_items['ldap'] = false;```

Comment: Then I added the code, the full code: ```public function getBranding() {$setting = Setting::getSettings(); $this->nav_items['branding'] = false; return view('settings.branding', compact('setting'));}```  but does not work. I don't know wether I put it in the wrong way or correct, since I am a beginner to laravel